# Neovim: Relative config file(init.vim) location

Tags: vim, path, neovim

I'm moving from vim to neovim, and my problem is that I need to carry it on portable USB sticks.
So I need to read config files from relative path. I used `$VIM/_vimrc` for this purpose on original vim, since `$VIM` always points to vim files in my USB. 
But Neovim stores config files in `~/.config` on Linux or `Appdata` on Windows, which both points to local computer's directory I was using.
Is their any relative directory Neovim uses to read config files? I don't want to manually source config file every single time...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From `:help startup`:

> ```
>     The Nvim config file is named "init.vim", located at:              
>             Unix            ~/.config/nvim/init.vim
>             Windows         ~/AppData/Local/nvim/init.vim            
>     Or if $XDG_CONFIG_HOME is defined:                                   
>                             $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/nvim/init.vim
> ```

So you can use `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` in a way similar to how you used `$VIM` before.

Instead of setting `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME`, you can make a bash alias, or an equivalent wrapper script:

```
alias vim="vim -u /path/to/vimrc"
```

Comment: Well what about on windows?

Comment: Also, XDG_CONFIG_HOME is not set if their wasn't any config file read at the startup.

Comment: No idea about Windows, it wasn't tagged. But basically, set it yourself in environment if it's always the same, or in a wrapper shortcut or batch file or whatever you use.

Comment: How to set or define $XDG_CONFIG_HOME manually on Windows 10?